# can a linear classifier based on two variables separate a dummy variable?

Tags: svm, linear, scatterplot

i have this problem :
[image]
as you can see, on the x-axis there is the variable `age` and on y-axis there is the `wkswrkd` which is basically week of work per year.
Moreover, i divided by 'status' rich and non rich people, here is the code by ggplot:

`ggplot(data = prgeng2, mapping = aes(x = age , y = wkswrkd))+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(col = rich,size = rich,shape = rich,fill = rich))+ 
  theme_light()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('yes' = 'gold3','no' = 'tomato3')) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c('yes' = 3,'no' = 1.75))`

now my question is this : can a linear classifier divide **yes** from **no** ?
bonus question : how can i improve this scatterplot using ggplot?

be kind, im totally new to this field.

Comment: Your data seems to seriously overlap. A linear classifier, which simply attempts to put a line between yes/no classes will not be useful in that case. However, there might be some higher dimension (say z-axis), where your 'yes' samples raise a bit to up. Then you can find a linear classifier to split z-dimension. This can be done by SVM.

Comment: thank you very much, now it's totally clear!